# launchd runs program every hour even though StartCalendarInterval array is provided

Tags: macos, launchd

I have my `StartCalendarInterval` set in my launchd plist file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>local.script.launcher</string>
        
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
        
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>osascript</string>
            <string>/Users/me/basic-script.scpt</string>
        </array>
        
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Hour</key>
                <integer>8</integer>
                <key>Minute</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Hour</key>
                <integer>16</integer>
                <key>Minute</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Hour</key>
                <integer>24</integer>
                <key>Minute</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Even though I am declaring 3 different `StartCalendarInterval`s, **the agent still launches the program every hour.**

What am I doing wrong?

.

## SOLUTION:

As per [@Phong's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/248766/100332), for `launchd` plist files and `StartCalendarInterval`, midnight, 12AM, or 2400 hours military time is `Hour = 0` not `24`.

Comment: Please post the whole plist file, as other parts of the file could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Updated.  I figured anyone that tries to help will want to see it, but Stack wouldn't let me post it as it said "too much code."

Comment: For Hour, you'll want to specify 0 rather than 24. I can't check right now, but I'm guessing it's throwing out the 24 as invalid, and just running on Minute 0. Also, you've unloaded and reloaded the agent after editing the plist?

Comment: Sweet! I will try it an let you know later today.  Def `unload`ed/`load`ed and then re`start`ed

Comment: @AndreBulatov Please post it to pastebin and link it here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`launchd` is throwing out *24* as an invalid **Hour** value, thus interpreting that entire entry as **Minute** = *0*. This causes your agent to run every hour on the dot.

The correct value for midnight is *0*:

```
<dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>0</integer>

    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
</dict>
```

Comment: Haven't reached midnight yet, but can already confirm that it resolved the problem because the hourly runs stopped and when I changed from `24` to `0`, I also added an entry for 11PM(23) and that worked perfectly.  Thank you!